# Beamer and XeLaTeX: ugly spacing of \prime in math mode

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing, xetex

If I compile the following MWE in XeLaTeX I get the result in the image:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$C'(x)$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the spacing of the prime is completely broken. If, on the other hand, I compile the same MWE with PDF-LaTeX the result is as expected:

[image]

This issue only seems to affect Beamer. If I typeset an `article` the spacing is as expected, even when compiling with XeLaTeX.

Does anyone know what is going wrong in the XeLaTeX-Beamer example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been discussed e.g. here https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/375
If you reset the letters font to T1 is works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\AtBeginDocument{%
      \DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{T1}{lmr}{\mddefault}{it}%
      }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$C'(x)$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]